# Cannot get text from UITextField - Swift - iOS

Tags: ios, string, swift, uitextfield, var

I have an iOS app written in Swift. I am struggling to get the text from the UITextField because my app crashes on this line of code:

```
let dataUser = self.userField.text
```

I get the following crash report:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

What am I doing wrong?... all I want to do is get the text from the text field.

Thanks, Dan.

Comment: Make sure that your UITextField is linked to the `userField` outlet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check in Interface Builder that your UITextField is properly linked to your "userField" IBOutlet: your UITextField, `self.userField`, is probably not hooked to the IBOutlet, so the object is nil and it crashes when trying to access its `.text` property.

Answer (score 2):

In swift 2.0 the text value of UITextField became optional.

So check if exists first:

```
guard let text = self.userField.text else {
  print("ooops")
  return
}

let dataUser = text
```

Comment: Wow I really like this approach its very safe. Thanks.