# When I try to change a UIlabel's text, I get an "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping value" in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, facebook, uilabel

I am building an app with Swift that fetches your email address, first name and last name from your Facebook profile once logged in and displays it on screen.

To make it simpler, I am focusing on making the email work and then I will work on the first and last name.

I created a label called EmailLabel that is supposed to display the email address on screen. However, when I try to change EmailLabel's text to the actual email address, I get the

```
Thread1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION ERROR (code=EXC_1386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
```

and the

```
fatal error:unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

message.

I know that the EmailLabel is always unwrapping as a nil.
To fix this I wrote:

```
self.EmailLabel = UILabel()
```

It stopped giving me the error but the EmailLabel wouldn't update its text to the actual email address.

I would really appreciate any help! By the way, I am quite new to programming so please try to give a simple answer :)

```
import UIKit
import FBSDKCoreKit 
import FBSDKLoginKit 

class ViewController: UIViewController, FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate { 

@IBOutlet var EmailLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var SomeLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    var loginButton = FBSDKLoginButton() 
    loginButton.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"] 
    loginButton.center = self.view.center 
    loginButton.delegate = self 
    self.view.addSubview(loginButton) 

}


func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result:FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!) { 

    fetchProfile() 
    if error == nil 
    {
        print("Login complete") 
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showInfo", sender: nil) 
    }
    else
    {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}

func fetchProfile(){
    print("fetchProfile")

    let parameters = ["fields": "email, first_name, last_name"]
    FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: parameters).startWithCompletionHandler { (connection, result, error) -> Void in

        if error != nil{
            print(error)
            return
        }

        if var email = result["email"] as? String {
            print(email)
            self.EmailLabel.text = "\(email)"
        }

        if let first_name = result["first_name"] as? String {
            print(first_name)
        }

        if let last_name = result["last_name"] as? String {
            print(last_name)
        }
    }
}

func loginButtonDidLogOut(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) { 

}

func loginButtonWillLogin(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) -> Bool { 
    return true
}


}
```

I tried looking at other questions but it isn't working

Is there a reason for the label being a nil apart from the IB Outlet not being connected?

Comment: Probably this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33129428/2227743

Comment: Check your IB outlet for `EmailLabel` is connected, also convention states that properties should start with a lowercase (i.e `emailLabel`)

Comment: Try updating the label in main queue thread

Comment: Thanks, I changed the EmailLabel to emailLabel and tried what Eric D said and read the what originaluser2 linked but it still isn't working.

Comment: iYoung, how can I update the label in main queue thread?

Comment: Is there a reason for the label being a nil apart from the IB Outlet not being connected?

Comment: @CarlaGaMe When is `fetchProfile` getting called? You might be trying to set the text of the label before it's loaded in. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29321383/iboutlet-is-nil-but-it-is-connected-in-storyboard-swift).

Comment: Thank you so much @originaluser2!!! That was it. I added an if-statement in the ViewDidLoad function: if emailLabel != nil{
                                               fetchProfile()
                                            }

Answer (score 2):

I added an if-statement in the ViewDidLoad function: 
    if emailLabel != nil{ 
        fetchProfile() 
    }
and it worked!

Thank you so much for all your help

Answer (score 0):

Your outlet is probably disconnected. `Cmd + click` from the label to your outlet in your code, and your label will not be nil anymore.